# select 0 in the first n numpy array dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(1,2,3,4,5,6,...)` (arbitrary length) and I would like to select the first entry in the first `n` columns, i.e.,

```py
def select_first_n_0(arr, n):
    if n == 1:
        return arr[0]
    elif n == 2:
        return arr[0][0]
    elif n == 2:
        return arr[0][0][0]
    # ...
```

Is there a more comprehensive expression for this?

Comment: Create an indexing **tuple**, e.g. `idx=(0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @hjpaul:

```py
def select_first_n_0(arr, n):
    return arr[tuple([0] * n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion

```
def select_first_n_0(arr, n):
   if n == 1:
      return arr[0]
   return select_first_n_0(arr[0], n-1)
```